# c# как мне сделать программу которая будет создавать case в switch до определенного числа?

Tags: c#, switch, case

c# как мне сделать программу которая будет создавать case в switch  до определенного числа?
ну например мне надо что бы программа создала количество кейсов  равное  значению переменной. Буду рад помощи)

Comment: "создать `case`" - это генерация кода. В скомпилированном коде такое не сделать. Опишите задачу конкретней, такое впечатление, что вы запутались.

Comment: я хочу создать программу с заметками , количество заметок пользователь забивает сам . Мне надо что бы если пользователь хочет обратиться к какой то  определенной то она бы открывалась и была бы возможность написать или исправить в ней текст. Я подумал что это можно сделать через swich но я не знаю точное количество заметок и получается что я запутался

Comment: Прочитайте про массивы, а затем про коллекции, у вас должно быть условно `var items = new List<Item>();` далее `items.Add(new Item(...));`, ну а получить обратно нужный `var item = Items.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name = "Супер заметка!")` (или что-то аналогичное).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, какой интерфейс вы используете, поэтому постараюсь описать только логику.

Первым делом создадим класс `Note`, который будет хранить информацию о заметке:

```cs
public class Note
{
    public string Name;
    public string Content;

    // При создании объекта вызывается этот метод
    public Note(string name, string content) =>
        (Name, Content) = (name, content);
}
```

Теперь создадим динамический список этих самых заметок и проинициализируем его пустым:

```cs
List<Note> notes = new(); // Создаём новый пустой массив
```

Ну и простейшие взаимодействия с этим списком:

```cs
// Добавляем заметку:
notes.Add(new Note("Заметка 1", "Это просто заметка №1"));

// Получаем заметку с именем "Заметка 1" (см. LINQ):
var note = notes.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "Заметка 1");

// Если заметка существует
if (note is not null)
{
    // Изменяем описание заметки
    note.Content += "\nДополнительное содержимое к заметке";
    // Так как мы работает с объектом, то изменяется оригинальный объект
    // (см. Ссылочные типы)

    // Удаляем заметку
    notes.Remove(note);
}
```